# SqlDataSource control and SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, sqldatasource

I'm testing a web page to prevent SQL Injection.Here is my ASPX page source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Test" runat="server"  
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Default %>" >    
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" Visible="False" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Test" ></asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind:

```
string ID = Request["id"];

SqlDataSource_Test.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = @ID";
SqlDataSource_Test.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("ID", System.Data.DbType.String, ID)); 

GV.DataBind();
```

but when I request the page with the url:

```
http://localhost:5284/details.aspx?id=731974'; update table set name='SQL INJECTION' where ID=1--&p=2
```

The field "name" is updated to "SQL INJECTION".

How to prevent SQL injection in `SqlDataSource` control?

Answer (score 0):

Change `new Parameter("ID", System.Data.DbType.String, ...)` to `new Parameter("ID", System.Data.DbType.Int32, ...)`.

Comment: The ID parameter must be an string

Comment: If so, create a stored procedure and pass @ID as parameter.